# error MSB6006: "fxc.exe" exited with code 1

Tags: c++, visual-c++, directx-11

i've searched the internet for this error for quite a while now and i can't find the answer to my problem, can anybody help me with this error?

My code for the Fx file is:

```
cbuffer cbPerObject
{
    float4x4 gWorldViewProj;
};

struct VertexIn
{
    float3 PosL : POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR;
};

struct VertexOut
{
    float4 PosH : SV_POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR;
};

VertexOut VS(VertexIn vin)
{
    VertexOut vout;
    vout.PosH = mul(float4(vin.PosL, 1.0f), gWorldViewProj);
    vout.Color = vin.Color;
    return vout;
}

float4 PS(VertexOut pin): SV_Target
{
    return pin.Color;
}

technique11 ColorTech
{
    pass P0
    {
        SetVertexShader( CompileShader( vs_5_0, VS() ) );
        SetGeometryShader( NULL );
        SetPixelShader( CompileShader(ps_5_0, PS() ) );
    }
}
```

and my code in the main program is this:

```
void BoxApp::BuildFX()
{
    DWORD shaderFlags = 0;

    ID3D10Blob * compiledShader;
    ID3D10Blob * compiledShaderMsgs;
    HRESULT hr = D3DX11CompileFromFile((LPSTR)"mColor.fx", 0, 0, "FXfile", "fx_5_0", shaderFlags, 0, 0, &compiledShader, &compiledShaderMsgs, 0);

    if (compiledShaderMsgs != 0)
    {
        MessageBoxA(0, (char*)compiledShaderMsgs->GetBufferPointer(), 0, 0);
        ReleaseCOM(compiledShaderMsgs);
    }

    D3DX11CreateEffectFromMemory(compiledShader->GetBufferPointer(), compiledShader->GetBufferSize(), 0, MainD3DDevice, &mFX);
    ReleaseCOM(compiledShader);

    mTech = mFX->GetTechniqueByName("ColorTech");
    mfxWorldViewProj = mFX->GetVariableByName("gWorldViewProj")->AsMatrix();
}
```

Thanks for the help already.

Comment: Sounds like `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`

Comment: All right, but what should i do then?

Comment: 3 simple options, search for EXIT_FAILURE in the code (but it is most likely in includes/libs) or use the debugger to step through until you get the error. Divide and conquer, put some logging in the code to find where it goes to and start the debugger from there.

Comment: I did some of that logging, but to no avail. i still get the same error.

Comment: You should be able to narrow it down by dividing up the code between two loggings with more loggings, *if* its a sequential problem and not a threading. Are any of these function call able to fail? is there a return code that should be checked or a throw that needs to be caught?

Comment: The only thing that is really possible to fail is that d3dx11compilefromfile fuction but the rest works fine. there are not return codes that need to be checked or throws.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing DX11 I can only guess that there is a critical check that is missing, when I compare your code to [this one](http://fancy-engine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fancy/Engine/Shader.cpp) I see a missing check for hr, and a missing return.

Comment: I have solved the problem, apperently i didn't set the format for the fx file right but now i got it. Thanks for all the help i really appreciate it.